# Как записать null в json питон

Tags: python, json, requests, null

```
json2 = {"id": f"{id}",
         "description": null,
         "dateTime": f"{dateTime}",
         "serviceId": f"{serviceid}",
         "shopId": f"{shopid}",
         "comment": null,
         "planAssignmentsCount": 2,
         "factTariffPeriod": f"{planTariffPeriod}",
         "factTariffValue": 1,
         "factAssignmentsCount": f"{userackt[4]}",
         "completedWorkCertificateStatus": "NOT_FORMED",
         "sentToBank": false}
r0 = requests.post("https://вап.сайт.ru/api/order/update", json=json2, headers=headersad,
                                   proxies=proxies)
```

Есть вот такой кусок кода, в нем есть json, который ругается на параметр null, если обернуть null в "" то тогда сайт выдает ошибку, а если обернуть весь это json в строку и использовать

```
json2 = json.loads(json2)
```

То тогда null заменяется на None(такой формат принимает питон), но сайт тоже выдает ошибку.А если после этого прогнать через json.dump(json2) то там уже получится null
но это строка, а не json.Как можно это решить?